# How to download file from machine on same network?

Tags: php, download

I have a Linux machine running a web server that provides a browser-based user interface over a local area network which I can access from a laptop connected to the same network using `http://linux_machine_ip_address/user_interface/index.php`.

On the Linux machine, a file exists that I'd like to be able to download from the laptop that views the user interface. What I'm imagining is a `Download` button on the web-gui that references the desired file path and downloads it over the network to the laptop.

I am not a web developer and am a bit unsure about how might I implement this? Would it be something like this? I'm not even sure this would work, is there a better way?

```
<a href="/results/data.csv" download>
<button class="mt-2 btn btn-primary btn-lg my-auto" style="width: 245px; font-size: medium;">Download Data</button>
</a>
```

Comment: `I'm not even sure this would work`...it will if that URL exists in the webserver on the Linux machine. This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Don't put a button inside an anchor link though. If you want to make the link _look_ like a button, then use CSS to style it.

Comment: Ok very useful.... maybe I'm not as far off as I thought then. Do you have a code snippet showing how I'd style it with CSS without the button inside the anchor link?

Comment: Well ordinarily I'd say "no, not specifically, it depends exactly how you want it to look" and suggest you type "make link look like button using CSS" into google in order to get a large number of existing suggestions you could use or adapt. However, from the classes you've used on your button I'm guessing you're using Bootstrap in your page, so actually you can just move those classes onto the anchor link instead and it'll do a good of it already for you - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/8n0ba7dp/